# Best practices for creating a CSV file?

Tags: ios, csv

I am working in Swift although perhaps the language is not as relevant, and I am creating a relatively simple CSV file.

I wanted to ask for some recommendations in creating the files, in particular:

1. Should I wrap each column/value in single or double quotes? Or nothing? I understand if I use quotes I'll need to escape them appropriately in case the text in my file legitimately has those values. Same for \r\n
2. Is it ok to end each line with \r\n ? Anything specific to Mac vs. Windows I need to think about?
3. What encoding should I use? I'd like to make sure my csv file can be read by most readers (so on mobile devices, mac, windows, etc.)

Any other recommendations / tips to make sure the quality of my CSV is ideal for most readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of apps that create CSV files.

Any column value that contains a newline or the field separator must be enclosed in quotes (double quotes is common, single quotes less so).

I end lines with just `\n`.

You may wish to give the user some options when creating the CSV file. Let them choose the field separator. While the comma is common, a tab is also common. You can also use a semi-colon, space, or other characters. Just be sure to properly quote values that contain the chosen field separator.

Using UTF-8 encoding is arguably the best choice for encoding the file. It lets you support all Unicode characters and just about any tool that supports CSV can handled UTF-8. It avoid any issues with platform specific encodings. But again, depending on the needs of your users, you may wish to give them the choice of encoding.

Comment: thanks so much for clarifying. So just to confirm, both my heading columns (the first row) as well as all of the values in each column below for every row should be quoted in ""'s (so "Name" \n "John Doe"\n "Jane Doe"\n etc? thanks!

Comment: No. You don't need to quote every value. Only if the value itself has a newline and/or a field separator. The newline at the end of each row doesn't require any values to be quoted. Of course you can quote every value but you only have to quote values that need it.